# Custom menu item in ActionBarSherlock

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock

I need to have a custom menu item in the ActionBar that just displays some custom formatted text. So I thought I would create an image on the fly and attach that to an menu icon. So  in my code I thought I could use Layout xml to compose my text:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:orientation="horizontal"
              android:layout_width="wrap_content"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <TextView android:textColor="#bcbcbb"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:layout_width="wrap_content"
              android:text="Some Text"/>
    <TextView android:textColor="#ffffff"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:layout_width="wrap_content"
              android:id="@+id/replace_text" android:text="XXXX"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Then create a temp layout drawing that to a DrawableBitmap:

```
        LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout)View.inflate(getApplicationContext(), R.layout.refund_text, null );
        layout.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
        layout.measure(View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED), View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED));
        layout.layout(0, 0, mRefundLayout.getWidth(), layout.getHeight());
        layout.buildDrawingCache(true);
        Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(layout.getDrawingCache());
        BitmapDrawable bm = new BitmapDrawable( getBaseContext().getResources(), bitmap);
        layout.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false);
....do something with the bitmap
```

However after the measure call width and height are still zero. Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Regards
Lee

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to control the colours of the text in the MenuItem, you might be able to simply get away with formatting (using SpannableStringBuilder) the CharSequence you pass to MenuItem.add(int groupId, int itemId, int order, CharSequence title). I haven't tried that, let us know if it works!

If you ultimatately want to do more than that then create your own custom ActionProvider, inflating your layout in onCreateActionView() and "doing stuff" in onPerformDefaultAction().